# Why do the inferred types differ between let f = List.map fst vs let g x = List.map fst x

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, the inferred type of

```ml
let f = List.map fst
```

is

```
val f : ('_weak1 * '_weak2) list -> '_weak1 list = <fun>
```

while the inferred type of

```ml
let g x = List.map fst x
```

is

```
val g : ('a * 'b) list -> 'a list = <fun>
```

(types taken from utop).

As a result of this, `f` cannot be used polymorphically, while `g` can.

Why does this eta conversion between pure functions cause such a difference in type inference?

Comment: I'd think it's exactly the same type, just using different names for the type variables.

Comment: it appears `'_weak1` has a special connotation in the ocaml type system.  If you try doing
`f [(1,0); (2, 0)];; f [("a", 0); ("b", 0)]`, the type checker will fail, however `g [(1,0); (2, 0)];; g [("a", 0); ("b", 0)]` passes fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is due to the *value restriction*, which does not allow the first definition to be polymorphic: it is defined by an application, which is not a value. The second form is defined as a function, which is a value. The notation `'_weakN` indicates a monomorphic type that is not yet resolved, as opposed to a polymorphic type variable like `'a`.

See [this chapter](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/polymorphism.html) for more background.

Comment: Many thanks for this!  I think I understand generally, however I'm confused by the point "it is defined by an application, which is not a value" - does this mean `List.map fst` is not a value?

Comment: Value in the syntactic sense, so no, an application is not a value, it is an expression computing a value. A lambda on the other hand is a syntactic value (of function type).